# How to read bean into other class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, autowired

I have this configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value ="com.cloudgatewayservice")
@PropertySources({@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml"),
                 @PropertySource("file:${prm.target.account.config}")})
public class AccountInstanceConfig {

    @Autowired private Environment env;


    @Bean public List<String> accountInstance() {
        return Arrays.asList(env.getRequiredProperty("prm-account-instance").split("#"));
    }
}
```

And I need to get the `accountInstance()` return values but I dont know how to do that. Could you please provide some help with that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `@Autowired` annotation?

On field:

```
@Autowired
private final List<String> accountInstance;
```

In constructor:

```
private final List<String> accountInstance;

@Autowired
public MyClass(List<String> accountInstance) {
    this.accountInstance = accountInstance;
}
```

Or with setter:

```
private List<String> accountInstance;

@Autowired
public void setAccountInstance(List<String> accountInstance) {
   this.accountInstance = accountInstance;
}
```